# expected expression/statement before

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I keep getting the above error(s) for the third line of the code extract below:

```
    while(getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0) {
        lineno++;
        if(strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except) {
```

When compiling it throws up two errors. 
One is 'expected expression before '!=' token
Second is 'expected statement before ')' token

As a novice programmer, I am not quite sure where to start apart from here. I've tried looking at similar questions regarding this error, but none seem to address my issue. Any/all assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Apparently, there's a method in asking 'smart' questions on here. Any/all assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `if(  (strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except)`

Comment: You have two conditionals **!=** in a single **if** statement.  Decide what you want to achieve, and edit accordingly.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: You either want to go for a smarter editor, or just getting the habit of counting opening and closing parentheses, brackets adjusting them until they match.

Answer (score 3):

Missing parenthesis `(` in `if(strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except)` line.

Comment: little oops, these are `braces`: '{' and '}'  The problem is the open/closing `parens`  '(' and ')' are not balanced.

Answer (score 0):

regarding this line:

```
if(strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except) {
```

There is a syntax error.

In general, the number of opening parens '(' must match the number of closing parens ')'

A corrected line would be:

```
if(  (strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except) {
  ^  ^      ^           ^        ^          ^
  +1 +2     +3          -3       -2         -1
```

however, that is not the only problem:

the prototype for the function: getline() has three parameters:

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

so this line:

```
while(getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0) {
```

does not compile!

When compiling, enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: Thank you for your comments/answer @Jean-Baptiste Yunès. It was simply a case of missing parentheses. Thought I had counted the openinhg and clsoing braces. But, guess ones eyes only sees what they wants to see.